# What does "index" stands for in TableRow.addView (View child, int index)?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it meaning that you can build a table row with an empty column ?

I want to do a TableLayout like this :

```
+--------------+---------------------+
+  *Nothing*   +     LinearLayout    +
+------------------------------------+
+ LinearLayout +      *Nothing*      +
+--------------+---------------------+
```

Is it possible with index property ?

```
TableRow topTableRow = new TableRow(context);
topTableRow.addView(xAxisScrollView, 1);
addView(topTableRow);

TableRow bottomTableRow = new TableRow(context);
bottomTableRow.addView(yAxisScrollView, 0);
addView(bottomTableRow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29), it should be possible. But I would just try it. It's done in 2 minutes ;)

Comment: I tried this but it throws an IndexOutOfBoundException ... :(

Comment: Ok I see, but this answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3345189/329637

Comment: Thanks, I will try with a GridView